# Properly pass time to laravel view from database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass date and time to my laravel view and it comes out as a `Carbon\Carbon` format which is not suitable to display. Here is a sample of what I tried that returned carbon format from my database.

```
$list["period"] = $model -> created_at;
```

Thanks and I am using 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format()` method:

```
$model->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
```

There are plenty of [other methods](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) available.

Comment: I have tried it, still returned Carbon\Carbon format no difference

Comment: Well, it returns string in `Y-m-d` format. So you should change format to whatever you like, for example try `format('d-m')` to see the difference.

Comment: this is what it returns    { ["period"]=> object(Carbon\Carbon)#213 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-09-02 14:57:07.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }

Comment: how do you format the code properly, sorry for my in-proper method, thanks

Comment: Double check everything, because if you're using `format()` method, you should get a string. What does `dd($model->created_at->format('Y'));` show?

Comment: thanks and sorry for later response, a var before that was causing the hiccup...thanks for the help really appreciate